# Pyinstaller: segmentation fault with simple hello world

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mavericks, pyinstaller

I'm trying to use Pyinstaller on Mavericks. The script that i'm testing is pretty simple:

```
print 'hello world'
```

And the pyinstaller line is:

```
pyinstaller.py --onedir --name=workd main.py
```

When I try to run the generated file I get:

```
$ build/workd/workd
[1]    4101 segmentation fault  build/workd/workd
```

I tried several pyinstaller  versions, including revision 12e40471c from their github repository.

What am i doing wrong?